# importing text files to spreadsheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am reading Automate the Boring Stuff with Python. Chapter 12 asks you to write a program to read in the contents of several text files (using readLines() and insert these into a spreadsheet.

After some trial and error I developed code that does this for two text files - however, I am curious if there are better / more efficient ways of doing this.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = 'Data'
test = open('data.txt')
data = test.readlines()

test2 = open('more_data.txt')
data2 = test2.readlines()

for i in range(1,5):
    cellref=sheet.cell(row=i, column=1)
    cellref.value=data[i-1]

for i in range(1,5):
    cellref=sheet.cell(row=i, column=2)
    cellref.value=data2[i-1]


wb.save("newer_data.xlsx")
```

I get the expected results but suspect my code could be improved

Comment: See and run it at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ProductiveSnappyAutomaticvectorization)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd say just have a look at the openpyxl docs. The book you have is okay but somewhat out of date.

Answer (score 1):

My version programmatically determines the number of files to process and loops through each placing the contents onto the spreadsheet. It should allow as many files as desired (though it wasn't rigorously tested).

```
#! python3
# Takes multiple text files as CLI arguments and writes
# each line to consecutive rows in a column
import openpyxl
import sys

# Open a blank workbook to populate.
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active

# Loop through the text files.
for arg in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    text_file = open(sys.argv[arg], 'r')
    text = text_file.readlines()
    for line in range(len(text)):
        sheet.cell(row=line+1,
                   column=arg,
                   value=text[line])

# Write spreadsheet file
wb.save('text_to_spreadsheet.xlsx')
print('DONE')`
```